# Georeferencing CAD floor plans

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing, cad, world-file

I am working on a project, where I need to georeference CAD data for buildings with several floors. I'm using ArcGIS for this. In earlier ArcGIS versions it was possible to simply georeference the first floor, save the georeference as .wld and apply this georeference to the other floors via an "Import"-button. In the newer ArcGIS versions, this button no longer exists.

In the "solutions" I found online it said, that you simply have to locate the .wld3 (not .wld anymore?) and .prj files in the homefolder of the CAD data and the georeference will apply automatically to the rest of the data. However, once I do that and try to load the other floor plans to my map, it doesn't work (ArcGIS tries to load the data endlessly).

I don't know if there is an easier way to do that or if I'm simply missing something out.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. It would help if you could [Edit] the Question to specify the exact software release in use now, and the release before.